# What is the meaning of "I have attitude"?

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrase-meaning

what does the phrase "I HAVE ATTITUDE" mean in this picture?

[image]

Comment: "Having attitude" means being tough in some sense. As in standing ones' ground.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial research efforts; for example, the first place to check for the meaning of a word would be a dictionary. In the OALD, *[attitude](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/attitude)* includes a meaning of *confident, sometimes aggressive behaviour that shows you do not care about other people’s opinions and that you want to do things in an individual way* which seems clear enough. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.

Comment: Of course, "having attitude" may simply mean that you're not on the level.

Comment: It's a pun.  Positive Mental Attitude: the generic meaning of "attitude."  But then "attitude" in large red all-caps has a more specific meaning: you "have attitude" means you're nobody's pushover, you don't let anyone get away with anything (e.g. disrespect).

Comment: But isn't the whole point of this question to ask what the idiom "I have attitude" means in this particular context as opposed to asking in general what "I have attitude" means? Doesn't that fall under "Word choice and usage" from the help centre? This is clearly a pun on PMS, and understanding that this is a pun on PMS makes the choice of "having attitude" much more understandable and interesting than just understanding what "having attitude" means as an idiom.

Answer (score 0):

***To have attitude*** is a relatively modern idiom, originating in the US. The OED still only includes it as a draft addition to the dictionary, from 1997. Though the examples go back to 1962.

It is in two parts  -senses 6a, and 6b.

> a. Aggressive or uncooperative behaviour; a resentful or antagonistic
>   manner. In phrs. to cop an attitude, to give attitude, etc., to assume
>   such a manner. slang (orig. U.S.).
>
> b. Hence, any highly independent or individual outlook, approach,
>   appearance, etc.; self-possession; style, swagger, front; esp. in with
>   (an) attitude. slang (orig. U.S.).

Though the OEd does not include it, it is sometimes expressed as ***an attitude problem***.

Answer (score -1):

As the comments on the question say, 'have attitude' is being tough/strong-willed/assertive/kick-ass.

The usage here emphasises this meaning even further though: 'I have P.M.A.' appears to be playing on 'I have PMS', i.e. premenstrual syndrome. Premenstrual syndrome is often associated with being grouchy and irritable, and with 'PMA', this slogan is slamming that stereotype with the result of coming out even more tough-skinned and strong than by just saying 'I have attitude'.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? I've answered the question and given an explanation for why the meaning of 'having attitude' comes out particularly strongly in context and thus why this question is different to the previous question about having attitude. Also why was the answer below downvoted?